# Scroll to Position Relative to ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

What would I have to do to scroll to a position X pixels away from an ID? For example, I want to scroll to 200px above #ex.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#ko1").click( function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#in').offset().top }, 1000 );
        });
        $("#ko2").click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#ex').offset().top }, 1000);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: `$('#in').offset().top - 200`

Comment: heh, when I tried it I did top: -200

Comment: well, I think I gave up too quickly before going here. Thanks Sime Vidas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ko1').click(function () {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#in').offset().top - 200
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract 200 from `offset().top`